# How can I format a String number to have space in android Edit Field

Tags: java

For example:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(100000);
```

The result will be

```
1,000,000 for 1000000
10,000 for 10000
1,000 for 1000
```

So, my question is : How can I make

```
1000 to 1 000
1000000 to 1 000 000
```

I use `# ### ###` and it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html), this can solve your issue :

```
new DecimalFormat("#,###,###", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.FRENCH))
```

**Output**

```
1 000 000
1 000
```

[**Ideone demo**](https://ideone.com/uTno4G)